# I need help making calculations in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, math

I'm new to php and mysql and I've created a table that looks like this:

```
   ID   | Item_Name |  Field 1  |  Field 2  |
--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
   1    |  Horses   |    21     |     4     |
   2    |  Rabbits  |    50     |     3     |
```

I need help performing calculations depending on user selection for example when the user selects horses and his input is 5, I want all fields in ID 1 to be added and display the result to the user eg 21+4+5 =30. How can I do that in php?

Comment: What kind of thing is 'field 1'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a simple MySQL query:

```
SELECT *, (`Field1` + `Field2` + `UserInput) as `total` 
FROM `table`
WHERE `Item_Name` = '$itemName'
```

Comment: do add qoutes around the string value in the where-clause